# Join one table rows with another table columns in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql, Need to join two tables as below scenario

```
Table One : questions{question_id,question}
Example: question_id  question
         q01          communication skills
         q02          reasoning skills
         q03          technical skills

Table Two : grades{grade_id,grade}
Example : grade_id  grade
          gr01      below avg
          gr02      avg
          gr03      good
          gr04      best

Want to join above two tables for below result
         question_id  question               gr01        gr02  gr03    gr04            
         q01          communication skills   below avg   avg   good    best 
         q02          reasoning skills       below avg   avg   good    best 
         q03          technical skills       below avg   avg   good    best
```

Please help if it is possible.

Comment: There is no relationship between two tables !

Comment: It is clear that there are no possible relation between the tables the way they are presented.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look to same tutorial on database design. There are many good ones on the web. In the mean time, this may help you a little bit:
It seems you may need a table for 'persons' or similar such as:

```
TABLE persons
person_id int autoincrement primary key
person_name varchar(45)
--------
persons_attributes
```

Then you will have a questions table recording when the attributes of a person were taken

```
Table questions
question_id int autoincrement primary key
personid int
date_input date
communication_skills_id int
reasoning_skills_id int
technical_skills_id int
```

and you may need extra tables for: communication_skills; reasoning_skills; and technical_skill with a format as:

```
TABLE xxx_skills
xxx_skill_id int 
grade varchar(30) #"below average", "average", "good","best"
```

Then you may join your tables as:

```
SELECT p.person_name, q.date_input, c.grade communication_skill, r.grade reasoning_skill, t.grade technical_skill
  FROM questions q
    INNER JOIN persons p
    on q.person_id = p.person_id
    INNER JOIN communication_skills c
    ON q.communication_id = c.communication_id
    INNER JOIN reasoning_skills r
    ON q.reasoning_skills_id = reasoning_skills_id
    INNER JOIN technical_skill t
    ON q.technical_skills_id = t.technical_skills_id;
```